# How do I get list of tokens owned by me?

Tags: json, solana

I want to get a list of tokens I currently own, for a given wallet public key.

Currently I am using `https://api.solscan.io/account/tokens?address="PUBLIC_KEY">&price=1` to get the tokens I own.

Okay. So I found this. Using the SPL Token ID as the program ID will return all the user owned tokens.

```js
connection
  .getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(
    new PublicKey("PUBLIC_KEY"),
    {
      programId: new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - provide SPL token id as program id. I searched a while to find this

Comment: Please, convert main info in your question into an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using `.getParsedProgramAccounts()` method of Connection class.

```js
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection } from "@solana/web3.js";

(async () => {
  const MY_WALLET_ADDRESS = "FriELggez2Dy3phZeHHAdpcoEXkKQVkv6tx3zDtCVP8T";
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

  const accounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
    {
      filters: [
        {
          dataSize: 165, // number of bytes
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 32, // number of bytes
            bytes: MY_WALLET_ADDRESS, // base58 encoded string
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );
})();
```

Link to detailed explanation: https://solanacookbook.com/ingredients/get-program-accounts.html#filters

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the JSON RPC call `getTokenAccountsByOwner`, where the owner will be the wallet's public key.

More info at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner

Comment: This shows only the last 90 tokens, right?

Comment: It's designed to provide everything, unless there's a limit imposed by the RPC node.

Comment: How to request so the tokens are sorted by recent first and limit the tokens count i.e the most recent 5 tokens added to account